# issue with seeking forward/backward using MPMoviePlayerController in iOS4

Tags: ios, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, uislider, nsnotification

I have a weird issue with the MPMoviePlayerController in iOS.

I have a MPMoviePlayerController with control style none.
Added my own UISlider to seek forward/backward in the movie.

Set up notifications to see a change in the playback state.

After setting player.currentPlaybackTime to a new value the playbackstate goes to MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward or MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward and stays in that state.

I would expect that when the seeking stops (new position found), and the player continues to play normally the playbackstate would go back to MPMoviePlaybachStatePlaying but it doesn't.

Is this normal behaviour or am I missing something?

Comment: That is not a normal behaviour. Are you using a remote stream or do you playback a local resource? When playing the same content using the standard player (e.g. via website), do things work as expected?

Comment: doesn't matter wheter I'm using a local resource or remote stream. In both cases I end up with a playbackstate 4 or 5 (seeking forward/backward). I would expect a MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification with playbackstate back to 1 (playing).

Comment: Have you tried different content files? I would suggest to try it using the BipBop example: http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

Comment: Already tried some different files too. But I will give it a try.

Comment: @Till I'm really stuck on this. I have put some [sample code](http://bit.ly/mm1jqN) together that reproduces this issue. The sample code plays a random song from the iPod. See the debug info for the playbackstate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with UISlider's property continuous. Set it to no and you will be notified when the state will change from Forward/Backward to Playing.

self.playerControlsView.slider.continuous = NO;

The issue i guess is that when the continuous property is set to YES. The slider will continue the action of sliding the user is providing it and not trigger the state change. And hence the state remains forward/backward. I am not very sure about this but the answer is somewhere on these lines.

Hope this helps someone :)